# Installing app on Devices(iPhone/iPod)

Tags: iphone

I have developed an application for iPhone and iPod touch. Now i want to install that app on the device. I have created a provisioning profile for the particular device. 
   My query is that, now to install the app on a device I have to add the provisioning profile of that device to xcode and after selecting the developer in build option in project info pane i build the project and send the build and provisioning profile to the user. 
     Is there any to install the app without doing the above task of building the project with the provisioning profile. 
     Means i have a build of an app and a newly downloaded provisioning profile. I will send the user both build and profile in a zip file. will the user be able to install the app on his/her device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a bit of a confusing description, but I think the answer is yes. I normally ZIP the app before sending. The user must install the profile then the app by draggin into applications in iTunes (windows) or just ot iTunes on the Dock (Mac)

Comment: Thanks for reply. let me check with what you have suggested. 

Above question what i want to say is without building the project with the provisioning profile for the device, can the user be able to install the app on device?

Comment: no, the only way for a user to install an app on the device is with a provisioning profile (unless you go down a JailBreak route - that's a different question)